# C# WP8 How to run code after user exits the application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Let's imagine I have a weather app and it has a tile on the main screen that shows the current temperature in NY. I want to update the temperature in that tile every 5min (after the user exists the app). How can I do that (run code after the user exits)?

Comment: the word "exit" may be inaccurate. It still runs, at background.

Answer (score 0):

You should use what's called [background agents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202942%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). Specifically, use a periodic task.